# Android Platform (TV): How to run a process at some common level where other android apps can pass data to it

Tags: android, android-tv

I would like to run a process (let's say eserver) as a standalone process or system level process to which other Android apps can obtain a handle from eserver and then pass the data to it. I am not able to find if it is possible at all to achieve it.

I have three different Android apps, if I bind this process eserver to each app individually then it works but I would like to break this coupling and make the process eserver running as a single entity (like the process can run on standard Linux system) so that I do not have to bind it to each Android app.

I tried to run this process from adb shell but then it was not possible from the app level to obtain a handle from it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this can be achieved by implementing AIDL interface which can be used to pass data between different apps.